# Spring Boot ResourceLoader not loading files from main resources in test context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a class using `ResourceLoader` for loading file in my `src/main/resources` directory.

```
ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader(MyClass.class.getClassLoader());
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(path);
File file = resource.getFile();
return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

This works fine when running the app but I also have a `@SpringBootTest` integration test using the same code. I would like to load the same resource from `main/resources` but it never finds the file on the provided path. It only works for files places in `src/test/resources` in that context.

Does anybody know how to force the integration test to search for resources in main resource directory instead of the test one when using `ResourceLoader`?

Comment: Have you tried `ClassPathResource`?

Comment: I tried at least three different ways of loading the file and the results is always the same... it also has to work in JAR files.

Comment: How are you running your tests? Gradle, Maven, IntelliJ? You might need to add `src/main/resources` to the test configuration classpath.

Comment: I am running them both in Gradle and from IntelliJ